# 64k is not a limit in android studio 2.2.2 ？

Tags: android, android-multidex

Recently，I update android studio to version **2.2.2** and the gradle version is **2.14.1**.

This afternoon,I found that the [64K   limit](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)  is not a problem. I used Android Studio to generate an apk and wanted to experience the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html) .When I opened the apk with APK Analyzer, I found it has 2 dex files,classes.dex and classes2.dex.

I realized my project exceed 65536 method references. However，I did not do anything to avoid the 64K limit. Android Studio just help us do it dynamicly. In classes.dex file, I found multidex.class. This made me confused，and I had a test：make 'multiDexEnabled' false，and generate apk again，still there are 2 dex files in the apk. It means the attribute 'multiDexEnabled' does not work any more.

I serched info about this for 2 hours,not get much . Any one can give me official document about this change？  Any help will be appreciated！

If I am wrong，please provide your test result and the config environment，thanks again.

update：
Guys，it's my mistake. there was a classes2.dex file in dependent library，studio  package it in apk. In fact，my project did not exceed 64k limit. For researching the 64k limit， I add additional librar to exceed 64k limit. According to official document ,I set the attribute ‘multiDexEnabled’ true in my build.gradle file，and  add multidex support library .

```
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            minSdkVersion 15 
            targetSdkVersion 25
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    }
```

However, the multidex conflict with support-v4 which contains classes concerned to multidex.So you should remove this line :

```
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'.
```

Then ,it worked. I generate an apk with 2 .dex file：classes.dex and classes2.dex. Now, I faced another problem, how does studio divide a dex file into 2 files？I will discuss the topic in another question，thank you all，guys.

Comment: I bet that you set minSdkVersion to 21 or more

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-on-l

Comment: This is up to the device - not the IDE. *Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files.*

Comment: It's because you have `multiDexEnabled true`